# Magento2 How to Show Sepereatly Configurable Product attribute and Product Custom Options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, configurable-product-options

Into Magento2 Configurable Product I want to add a Customizable Options.

But both the Configurable Product and Customizable option display into the same class.

[image]

Please check first size option is configurable option and second size is a product customizable option.

I want to product customizable option into the new div and display both in a sepreatly.

Comment: Please add more description to understand question.

Comment: Please check the update question @WebDeveloper

Comment: Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options.phtml#L27

This is applicable for rendering custom options you can override it and customize as per your need.

Comment: It is customize both configurable product options and customizable product option but i want to only customize customizable product option

Comment: Check block `product.info.options` for Custom Options and `product.info.options.wrapper` for Configurable Swatches. You can override layout and create custom container with So that you can customize HTML structure.

Comment: Hello it is worked thank you so much @WebDeveloper

Comment: Great I've posted it as answer. Kinldly provide time to accept as solution and give up vote to help other users as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86647/discussion-between-hardik-makwana-and-web-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options.phtml#L27 T

This is applicable for rendering **custom options** you can override it and customize as per your need.

Check block `product.info.options` for Custom Options and `product.info.options.wrapper` for Configurable Swatches. You can override layout and create custom container with So that you can customize HTML structure.